# Update custom folder metadata via Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, flow, microsoft-flow

My apologies, I am a bit of a novice with SharePoint and I can't use code. I am using SharePoint online.

Our organisation has a Sales Manager and Support Manager for each customer. Each customer has their own individual set of documents, so they have been grouped by folder as opposed to metadata.

To help managers filter the folders they need, I have created a custom folder content type, called 'Customer Folder'. This has a People or Group choice option for Sales Manager and Support Manager.

The folders are created via a form trigger on Flow; in the form, users are asked for the relevant Sales Manager and Support Manager. Is it possible to add the manager names as metadata for the custom folder through Flow, or does this need to be done manually?

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the folder, the folder action will return the ID of the folder. Add another action after create folder to save this ID in a variable. Now, add an action to "Update File Properties" and use this ID variable in "Id" and then, fill your Manager Name column with email Id of the desired user. Refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope it helps solve your problem. Please Upvote and mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the fix today and it worked like a charm!