# Inheriting metadata upward?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, modern-experience, folder

Is it possible to have a parent folder inherit metadata from child elements, i.e. upwards?

For example:

- The folder "folder" contains "file.txt"
- The column is "Language"

I set language to "English" and the "Language" column shows that value for file.txt.

However, one level above, the "folder" does not show "English" in its "Language" column.

Is this possible? Downward inheritance I know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upward metadata inheritance is not possible automatically using the SharePoint Online out of the box features.

Here are few options you can try:

1. Update folder metadata manually:

   You cannot update the language column value against folder using the "properties" form. However, there is a way to update the folder metadata using **Edit in grid view** option.

   Check this article for more information: [4 ways to tag folders with metadata in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/4-ways-to-tag-folders-with-metadata-in-sharepoint/)
2. Use Power Automate flow to update folder metadata:

   - Configure and run the Power Automate flow on file modifications in your document library.
   - You can get the parent folder relative URL using Path or Folder Path property from trigger outputs
   - Update the folder metadata with the help of folder information and "Update file properties" action.
   - Check this thread for reference: [Update custom folder metadata via Flow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269936/update-custom-folder-metadata-via-flow)

Comment: Thank you, Power Automate looks to be a good option.